# How To Convert List Object to JavaDStream Spark?

Tags: java, apache-spark, spark-streaming, sparkcore

i have List object bellow:

```
List<Tuple2<Tuple3<String, Long, Object>, Tuple2<Long, Object[]>>> rddQueue =
    Arrays.asList(tupleList);
```

how can convert its to JavaDStream Spark ? 
thank advance !

Comment: I don't think you can create JavaDStream from List<Tuple2>, BTW, why do you want to do that?

Comment: Try creating JavaDStream from one of the options available in `JavaStreamingContext` https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.0/api/java/index.html?org/apache/spark/streaming/api/java/JavaStreamingContext.html

Comment: What you can do is first create a `JavaRDD` using sparkContext.parallelize() method, then use that JavaRDD to create `JavaDStream` using `queueStream` method available on `JavaStreamingContext`

Answer (score 5):

You can do that using the `JavaStreamingContext` and a `Queue<T>`:

```
List<Tuple2<Tuple3<String, Long, Object>, Tuple2<Long, Object[]>>> 
  list = Arrays.asList();

// Random batch time, for the sake of the example.
JavaStreamingContext jssc = 
  new JavaStreamingContext("local[*]", "TestApp", new Duration(4000));

Queue<JavaRDD<Tuple2<Tuple3<String, Long, Object>, Tuple2<Long, Object[]>>>> rddQueue = 
  new LinkedList<>();

rddQueue.add(jssc.sparkContext().parallelize(list));

JavaDStream<Tuple2<Tuple3<String, Long, Object>, Tuple2<Long, Object[]>>> dStream = 
  jssc.queueStream(rddQueue);
```